# How to use Dino Spawning pads

Tags: lego-jurassic-world

I cannot figure out how to get the red brick for the 4x points. I've found the rock and used the gyrosphere to smash it away but I can't figure out how to get the t-rex from the dino pad. I know I've unlocked it because I broke the glass in the vending machine in the control room.

What do I press once I'm standing on the dino pad? Is it just triangle and then choose a dinosaur? I've read that you need a larger pad to get a larger dino and I've tried both pads in the area but neither will give me a trex.